# Rendering root as null (rendering in DOMless scope)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I wanted to render null at the root, so I can have a full tree that renders null, but just take advantage of the component (+ its lifecyle methods) structure of React.

Here is some info about "returning null concept": https://github.com/joshwcomeau/return-null - a lighting talk from react conf.

I am making an electron app. In the main scope, there is no dom. In this main scope (index.js) I have my redux store, I return null in the whole tree, including the root. However I can't initially render it because for initial render I am required to use ReactDOM.render like this:

```
ReactDOM.render(<AllNullStuff />, document.getElementById('something'))
```

I have no DOM, is there anyway to render it?

If I try `null` as root I get error:

> Error: _registerComponent(...): Target container is not a DOM element.

Is there any way to render a fully `null` tree so no DOM is required?

Comment: This is interesting aswell as weird. Higher level of abstraction. How is it supposed to work? Render stuff inside React**DOM**, when actually... nothing has to be rendered. :))

Comment: Thanks @Kinduser for the comment! :) It is so useful, I was able to pull this off in browser extensions, because even the main/entry "background" index.js has a DOM, so I would render an empty div, then the rest of my components were `null`. The background tree just is there to respond to state changes. The `componentDidUpdate`, `componentDidMount`, and `componentWillUnmount` are the most heavily used in `return null;` elements, while the `render` method is not used at all.

Comment: Would love to help you, but I can't :( Maybe you should look for some hints on React's github etc :)

Comment: Thanks sir for your motivational comment! I will definitely keep trying in that direction and update you on solution :)  @Kinduser

Comment: it would appear to me that your issue is not the `null` tree itself but the thing you're trying to render it into not existing (see "**target container** is not a DOM element"). So, really all it depends on is what you mean when you say you have no DOM. Can you not even use a throwaway DOM element, `document.createElement('div')` stylee? If not, then yeah it's still possible, but you'll need to use React outside of the DOM, like React Native does. I don't know the ins and outs of this but React certainly doesn't *need* a DOM to work in general.

Comment: Thanks @alexrussell for that. I cannot create a div even :( Oh yah RN does this!

Answer (score 0):

1. Electron have DOM.
2. If you don't have DOM, that means there no way to render it. How you render DOM in place where it's not exist?
3. Check p1, you have DOM in electron app, and after some configurations it's fully equal to website development, seems like you doing something wrong.
4. You cannot have tree. Yes, you can put null into any other tag, but null itself cannot have childrens.

Like this.

If you render null into #root, it will be shown as empty tag, but inside of it it's not possible.

```
render() {
    return null; //how to put child tags in it? No way...
}
```

Comment: Thanks Maksym, I was trying to render in the Electron background page where there is no DOM. React Native also has no DOM so it's interesting how they do it, I wish it was more well known/documented on how to bootstrap to DOM-less.